# What is the icon in the bottom-left corner of Windows Media Player 12?

Tags: icons, windows-media-player

There is an icon in the bottom-left hand corner of WMP12 that looks kind of like a progress bar. If you click it, it disappears. If you then click the place in the interface where it was, it re-appears. This makes me believe it is some kinda of toggle switch. Unfortunately, it does display any kind of tool-tip when you hover over it.

Does anybody know what this icon is and what it is used for?

[image: Here is a close-up of the icon itself]

[image: Here is the whole WMP UI, showing the icon in the bottom-left]

Comment: When playing streaming media, it used to be some sort of "Buffering..." indicator several versions ago.

Comment: Maybe it enables/disables buffering? Does anybody know for sure? How could I even test this?